# Dynamically update RecycleView from inside an AsyncTask

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DeviceAdapter deviceAdapter;
    List<Device> deviceList;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Context context = this;

    g.IP = cf.getIP(this);
    g.subNet = g.IP.substring(0, g.IP.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

    deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for(int i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
                if(cf.isUp(g.subNet + i, 80)) {
                    deviceList.add(new Device(g.subNet + i, "PAUSED", "N/A"));
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            deviceAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(context, deviceList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Which checks if a host is online, and if their port 80 is open, then at the end of the scan, it adds them all to the `RecyclerView`.

I was wondering how I could add:

```
deviceAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(context, deviceList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);
```

to the `doInBackground()` if statement, like this:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    for(int i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
        if(cf.isUp(g.subNet + i, 80)) {
            deviceList.add(new Device(g.subNet + i, "UP", "OPEN"));

            deviceAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(context, deviceList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

but without it crashing my app, so that the `RecyclerView` updates straight away when a new item is added to `deviceList<>`, rather then when the task is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because only the main thread can handle UI elements such as `RecyclerView`. So what you need to do is create a listener that will be called whenever your `AsyncTask` finds a new device.

Example:

```
public interface OnDeviceFoundListener {
    void onDeviceFound(Device device);
}

@Override
protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
        if (cf.isUp(g.subNet + 1, 80)) {
            listener.onDeviceFound(new Device(g.subNet + 1, "UP", "OPEN"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the Activity or Fragment where the RecyclerView is located, you will implement this listener interface, for example:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDeviceFoundListener {

    private List<Device> devices;

    @Override
    public void onDeviceFound(Device device) {
        devices.add(device);
        deviceAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(context, devices);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Don't forget to call the `notifyDataSetChanged` method in your adapter after you add the new device(s) you add.